# SQL query to generate a single row with a derived column based on presence of value in the child records

Tags: sql

I have a scenario like :

**Table A**

```
COL1(PRIMARY) 
REC1
REC2
```

**Table B**

```
COL1(PRIMARY) COL2(foreign key to col1 in table A) COL3
B_REC1         REC1                                VAL1
B_REC2         REC1                                VAL2
B_REC3         REC1                                VAL2
B_REC4         REC2                                VAL1
```

I want a query which will produce result as

```
REC1 true
REC2 false
```

The second column in the query is not a actual column but its value is derived from existence/non existence of VAL2 in COL3 of TABLE B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can produce the desired result

```
Select distinct
  a.COL1, 
  case when b.COL1 is null then false else true end as Flag
from TableA a 
left join TableB b on a.COL1 = b.COL2 and b.COL3 = 'VAL2'
```

Thanks Impaler :-)

Comment: if you can add a distinct, it would do the job for me

Comment: This works well if there's at most one row with value `VAL2` in `TableB`. The question is not clear, but I'll assume so. +1

Comment: @TheImpaler, thats not the case, there could be more than one rows in table B with VAL2

Comment: Then @zip, add a `DISTINCT` clause right after the `SELECT`.

Comment: @zip, you need to change b.col1 to b.col3

Comment: @user2599052, indeed we can do that. In both case the result will be the same because that if b.COL3 is null then b.COL1 too. we are join with the table TableB  filtered with just the rows with b.COL3 = 'VAL2'.

Answer (score 0):

`exists` should be the most efficient way to handle this:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from tableB b
                          where b.col2 = a.col1 and b.col3 = 'VAL2'
                         )
             then true else false
        end)
from tableA a;
```

You want an index on `tableB(col2, col3)`.